# postgres scheduler - external tool or inside settings?

Tags: postgresql, scheduled-tasks

I have few functions that need to run every day at certain time. Is there any way to schedule it from postgres? or do I have to use an external tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you have is to make use of pgAgent.  http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.8/pgagent.html